# decode base64 utf-8 string java

Tags: java, string, utf-8, base64

I have this string

```
"=?UTF-8?B?VGLNBGNDQA==?="
```

to decode in a standard java String.
I wrote this quick and dirty main to get the String, but I'm having troubles

```
String s = "=?UTF-8?B?VGLNBGNDQA==?=";
s = s.split("=\\?UTF-8\\?B\\?")[1].split("\\?=")[0];
System.out.println(s);
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
String x = new String(decoded, "UTF8");
System.out.println(decoded);
System.out.println(x);
```

It is actually printing a strange string

```
"Tb�cC@"
```

I do not know what is the text behind the encoded string, but I can assume my program works, since I can convert without problems any other encoded string, for example

```
"=?UTF-8?B?SGlfR3V5cyE="
```

That is "Hi_Guys!".

Should I assume that string is malformed?

Comment: You should try an online base 64 decoder first, so you can see what is the actual string (if it is well formed) and then evaluate if your code is working or not.

Comment: How do you know that it's Base64? As it has only uppercase characters it might be something else.

Comment: @SubOptimal

I'm pretty new to this but...isn't the "=?UTF-8?B?" mean that the following stuff is a base64 encoded utf-8 string?

Comment: As did not mention where this string is comming from it was a guess. If the string is using MIME encoding, then yes `=?UTF-8?B?...?=` denotes Base64 encoding. So the string is decodes as `TbcC@` (the character after the b is 0xCD04). If the font your are using cannot display a character it is displayed as � which is the [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)).